# How to check if a subset is included into a set?

Tags: delphi, set, operators, delphi-2007

I have two set type variables and I need to check if the first is a subset of the second one.

```
type
  TMyValue = (mvOne, mvTwo, mvThree);
  TMyValues = set of TMyValue;

...

var
  V1 : TMyValues;
  V2 : TMyValues;
begin
  V1 := [mvOne, mvTwo];
  V2 := [mvOne, mvTwo, mvThree];

  if(V1 in V2)
  then ShowMessage('V1 is a subset of V2')
  else ShowMessage('V2 is not a subset of V2');
end;
```

The example code gives me the following error on compiling:

> [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(36): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TMyValues' and
>   'TMyValue'

Is there an operator or an "embedded function" to check if values of V1 are all in V2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set operator `<=` allow to check whether V1 is subset of V2 ([reference to online help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Set_Operators))

```
if(V1 <= V2)...
```

Note that empty set is subset of any set.

Operator `in` should check appearance of single element in set, so it's usage was wrong here.